# "Cannot execute boolean operation"

Tags: modifiers

As you can see from my image, I am trying to subtract the mesh "Subtract" from the mesh "Cube"

[image]

However blender is giving me the error "Cannot execute boolean operation"

What is causing this problem?

Comment: can you upload your blend file?  http://www.pasteall.org/

Comment: wasnt too sure where to upload it so i put it on mega: https://mega.co.nz/#!gEZnCBxD!9onl-J0HoJTRNGqq4V6wrAkfdfhorYdCVAVzQ0EOZH0

Comment: Is that cube 2D?

Comment: @user3789776 do you want to join the two objects into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like blender has trouble performing boolean operation on meshes with large ngons. There is a very easy workaround for this problem.

---

1. Select the face that will hold the window

This single polygon has 8 vertices, more than 4 vertices is considered an ngon

[image]

2. Triangulate it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, this will make many triangles out of the big ngon
3. (optional step) With the polygons still selected, you can reduce the number of triangles by converting tris to quads by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

---

**Final Result**

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly! Will this fix most occurrences of this issue?

Comment: Yes, if not all.